# Is it possible to implement Scrapy into a dekstop app?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Can Scrapy be implemented in my custom desktop app where it automates the scraping process on a lists of webpages and export it as table into database?

Comment: Use PyQt or thinkter.  Use scarpy imports on PyQT. PyQT reference link: https://build-system.fman.io/pyqt5-tutorial

Comment: is python powerful in GUI app? because i have other features to be implemented as well

Comment: It depends on what kind of application you are developing. They covers most needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I have done the same via python, PYQT5, scrapy and Database.

```
1. Create the application frontend using Pyqt5(GUI,Designer option available ).
2. Create scrapy project and run the spider via python script scrapy call.
   If you are deploying the spider in any services, use the service API call.
3. Check the database connectivity in the frontend itself. 
   if it succeeds, save the spider response to the corresponding database. 
4. Use pyinstaller or py2exe to convert the code to a standalone executable.
```

Comment: so for the 2nd step i just implement a button in GUI and invoke the scrapy script to run right? and what do u mean by the deploying spider in service? sorry im new to this..

Comment: I mean if you are keeping the spiders in scrapyard or scraping hub (remote), then use the API call to run the scrapy spider. else if files are together, then a call from python script is enough.

Comment: is it ok if i can contact you personally if i face any difficulty in the future? it seems like you have done the same thing I want and any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: how do i contact you? whatsapp or facebook maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, if you are using `scrapy` `python` **scraped** the web pages and stored the desired data into any database you want and then periodically pick the data from database and show it in Desktop app. Desktop app can be of any framework or language.

Comment: how about implementing the scrapy framework in the desktop app instead of doing externally then display it in the app? is it possible?

Comment: like using it as api in the GUI app